# Loading Page in android

Tags: android, android-activity

How can I make loading page in android? I want it when my application starts.
Like the loading pages in games?
Could You help me with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are loads of examples in the internet, search by "splash screen"

http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?t=815

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing it would be to set your contentview in `onCreate()` then do all the loading in an async task and when that finishes load the 'real' layout in the onPostExecute. Check out http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

That way you load your "real" layout when it actually finishes loading rather than picking a generic time  to switch views. This is of course assuming that you want a loading page and not a splash screen. If you want that, checkout the other answers.

Here's a quick example... Say you have a file called Hello.java .. You'd set your content view to your loading layout in `OnCreate()` then call this class with something like.. new `DownloadFilesTask().execute();` put this private class in it...

```
  private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

 protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
     //grab stuff from the server, compute pi to 100000 places etc.
 }

 public void onPostExecute(String result) {
     //this will now switch us to our real layout, you can now do all your fancy UI stuff! :)
     setContentView(R.layout.reallayout);
 }
}
```

Basically this is multithreading the easy way. `onPostExecute` runs back on the UI thread (your main one) while `doInBackground` does everything on a separate thread so no black screens! I'd really urge you not to use `Runnable` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You mean a splash screen right? a simple google search would reveal a lot :)

[This piece of work](http://www.droidnova.com/how-to-create-a-splash-screen,561.html) helped me to make a splash screen.

Rather than copy and pasting the code, try to understand how he uses Threading with a time limit to achieve this target.

Comment: This is a fairly dirty way of going about the task. Why would you resort to sleep's and Runnable when Android provides ASyncTask ? It's available from 1.5+